# AngularJS filter for boolean true or false or all

Tags: angularjs, filter

I use this ngRepeat and now I will filter for **communicationUserConnections** where **communicationUserConnection#executed** is true. 
IS there a possibility to do this

```
data-ng-repeat="communicationUserConnection in vm.communicationUserConnections | filter:executed=vm.mySelectedValue.
```

If **vm.mySelectedValue** is true than show all communicationUserConnection where executed == true, otherwise show all communicationUserConnection's

Comment: Try | filter:executed:vm.mySelectedValue. Or you can always create a filter function and deal with it in your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

```
data-ng-repeat="communicationUserConnection in vm.communicationUserConnections |filter:{'executed':vm.mySelectedValue}"
```